# visual studio 2019 has stopped working upon start-up

Tags: crash, c++

VS 2019 crashes each time I try to start it up.

If I start it up normally, it prompts me to sign in.  After I click sign in, it says "Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 has stopped working" and gives me the choice to either Debug or Close program.  (I always choose "Close program".)

I tried the "devenv /resetusersettings" and "devenv /resetsettings" tricks; neither helped.

Starting in safe mode ("devenv /safemode") just gives the "Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 has stopped working" immediately.

I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling.  No go.

In other words, I cannot get VS 2019 to start at all.

Other info: at some point in the past, I installed Visual Studio Preview 2019, but uninstalled it since.  Also, I had installed it on my D:\ drive.  I only had the 30-day trial for the preview.

While I had it installed, VS 2015 worked perfectly for a long time, but then it had the "Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 has stopped working" problem.  It was suggested that I upgrade to to VS 2019 to fix the problem, but it looks like it has exactly same problem.

[image: Sign In produces a crash]

Comment: I have the same issue, but only on one of three installations.

Answer (score 2):

Bizarrely, I ran VS 2019 through [WinDbg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg) and it started working!
Now, I can run it without the WinDbg shell and it seems fine.